# Loading images on a web page using mootools when user scrolls page down

Tags: javascript, mootools

Does anyone know a library that would automatically load images as user scrolls down?  The idea is that I want to add user avatars on a wall dynamically when viewport changes.  The related HTML would be something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
  <a class="avatar" rel="nick" href="users/nick"></a>
  <p>comment goes here</p>
</div>
```

When user scrolls the page down the html needs to be changed like this:

```
<a class="avatar loaded" rel="nick" href="users/nick">
  <img src="avatars/nick.png"/></a>
```

Additionally, caching images should be possible too to minimize the traffic to backend if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [LazyLoad](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-lazyload) by David Walsh.  There's also a [LazyLoad for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) by a different author.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I wanted.  Now that I think of it, I remember seeing it when it was posted but completely forgot where I saw it.  Thanks!